# Was it arranged?

Tags: plot-explanation, southpaw

Was the win in *Southpaw* arranged? I'm asking this based on the fact that Hope himself mentions Jordan Mains 'paying' a decision win over Night Train early in the movie. Also, it's a close fight for most of the bout and taking in account the split decision for 115-113, 115-114, 116-112, plus the point they took from Escobar.

Is there any chance Mains had paid the win?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's left intentionally vague. Both Billy in-universe, and others out of universe seem to think the fight was fixed, but nothing is confirmed in the film. [So much that actual boxers have chimed in](http://www.latintimes.com/oscar-de-la-hoya-criticizes-southpaw-portraying-boxers-stereotypical-ways-332723):

> "[P]romoters fixing fights. Has this type of behavior reared its head in the history of our sport? At times, unfortunately, yes. Is it common? Absolutely not,” said de [Oscar de la Hoya].

Billy of course turns a blind eye to it because [he has more important things to deal with](http://www.npr.org/2015/07/23/424995597/southpaw-makes-a-bruised-bruiser-out-of-jake-gyllenhaal):

> Billy's need for income, so that he can convince a judge that he's fit for fatherhood, is what sends him to the gym run by Tick Wills, who trained the only boxer ever to beat him. **(Billy still got the decision, but he suspects that was because someone in his camp paid a bribe. "The fight game, you know," he shrugs.)**

Obviously, Billy isn't in on the fix, but he isn't a fool either. He won't take a dive but he won't say anything if someone else does.